# SSIS: Export and import CSV file with special characters

Tags: mysql, csv, ssis, export-to-csv, import-from-csv

I have to export a CSV file from a database using SSIS. 
It's very easy to do that, but the problems come when I have to import the same CSV file into another database (from another server) because I have 2 columns which contains characters like: comma (,), apostrophe ('), semicolon (;), colon (:), vertical bar (|).
I don't know which should be the settings for the Flat File Connection, which should be the header row delimiter, row delimiter, column delimiter...in order to to the both actions (export and then import).

I tried many combinations but I still get errors like:

> [Flat File Source [2]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data
>   conversion for column "ActiveJobs" returned status value 2 and status
>   text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of
>   data.". The data is mixing there because of the characters and spaces.

Comment: You could try using the Format: fixed width in Flat File Connection Manager. In this way the columns have fixed size, and the system does not care about separators.

Answer (score 1):

In SSIS you have the option of specifying a text delimiter\qualifier for flat text files. You could use this to export columns that have special characters. For example if your row looks like:

`column1value co,lumn2value co;lumn3value`

then the exported row using '**,**' as the column delimiter and '**"**' as the text delimiter would look like 
`"column1value","co,lumn2value","co;lumn3value"`

I don't remember what happens if you have a value like 
`co"lumn4value or "column4value"`

but I think that you can use as a delimiter any character as text delimiter if you have issues with double quotes. for example '•' (alt + 0149)